# What is the best way to implement STFT (Short-time Fourier transform) in Julia

Tags: fft, julia

So, I'm wondering how to implement a [STFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform) in Julia, possibly using a Hamming window. I can't find anything on the internet.

What is the best way to do it? I'd prefer not to use Python libraries, but pure native Julia if possible. Maybe it's a feature still being developed in Juila...?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you can just do what it says in the first paragraph of the linked Wikipedia page: take the FFT of sections (windows) of the time series? What does this miss?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not aware of any native STFT implementation in Julia. As David stated in his comment, you will have to implement this yourself. This is fairly straightforward:

1) Break up your signal into short time sections

2) Apply your window of choice (in your case, Hamming)

3) Take the FFT using Julia's `fft` function.

All of the above are fairly standard mathematical operations and you will find a lot of references online. The below code generates a Hamming window if you don't have one already (watch out for Julia's `1-indexing` when using online references as a lot of the signal processing reference material likes to use `0-indexing` when describing window generation).

```
Wb = Array(Float64, N)
## Hamming Window Generation
for n in 1:N  
    Wb[n] = 0.54-0.46cos(2pi*(n-1)/N)
end
```

You could also use the Hamming window function from [DSP.jl](https://github.com/JuliaDSP/DSP.jl).

P.S If you are running Julia on OS X, check out the Julia [interface](https://github.com/JuliaLang/AppleAccelerate.jl) to Apple's Accelerate framework. This provides a very fast Hamming window implementation, as well as convolution and elementwise multiplication functions that might be helpful.